# Looking for a setup / software solution for Media Playback

Tags: video, streaming-video, media

Disclaimer: I have a Raspberry B+

My RPi is currently connected to my amplifier (via cinch). I set it up as an Airplay Receiver and it works well for music (mostly Spotify).

Now I want to use it as an interface for video aswell. Unfortunatly Airplay doesnt work for Video on RPi. I have looked into Kodi (OMSC) and found it way too slow and probably too bloated for my use case. I have movies and stuff on a NAS which is available via network.

My Goal: Play Videos from NAS on my RPi connected to my TV (HDMI). I still want to listen to Music. A Spotify Connect solution would be fine too, since Airplay is just a tool for that matter.

My Problem: I am not sure what exactly I need to reach that goal. I imagine connecting to the RPi via a web page and just starting a video / spotify playlist from there.

Is such a thing possible and if so how?

Update: I have found an almost identical question here: [Stream videos wirelessly from PC to Pi to TV?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11967/stream-videos-wirelessly-from-pc-to-pi-to-tv)
Everyone seems to suggest Kodi. Is there no way around it?

Comment: Did you try XBian or LibreELEC instead ? Those distros may be optimized differently , perhaps they perform better.